# Passwordless login for new users in Communities

Tags: community, login

I´m testing passwordless login for Communities and I have created a successful example.

My idea is to simplify the login process for users who don't want to remember a password and also keep at the same time the user+password process.

The problem is for new users that have never accessed to the community. The passwordless login works properly but the first time they access, the system asks them for a new password.

¿Is there a way to use passwordless login for new users without asking for a new password if they access the community for the first time?

Regards.

Comment: Are you taking about Discoverable Login and Configurable Self-Registration, where you can login using your mobile phone number instead of an email address?  See the [External Identify Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_passwordless_login_about.htm)

Comment: @DavidCheng I'm talking about the possibility of giving access to the users to the community only with a code sent via email (passwordless login). This really works but if the user has never accessed to the community the system asks them to put a password for the first time. If the user has introduced a password previously, the next time they ask for a code for login, they can log in without a password.

Comment: Did you check this Salesforce. we were facing the same issue and Salesforce responded that it is as per design which feels really unintuitive.